# Twitter feed doesn't work over HTTPS

Tags: ssl, twitter

We recently installed a SSL certificate on our website, all content must be over HTTPS since the whole site runs on SSL.

We have the following twitter feed which gets built in the code behind and then passed to the view.

```
sb.Append("<div class=\"twitterWidget\"><a class=\"twitter-timeline\" href=\"https://twitter.com/pageName\" data-widget-id=\"545121545454787854\" data-chrome=\"nofooter noscrollbar transparent\" data-tweet-limit=\"3\">Tweets by @pageName</a>");
```

Now before this use to be http://twitter..... which worked perfectly, but now we have the SSL it needs to be HTTPS which I have done, but it no longer shows the feed on the page? I'm unfamiliar with the twitter feed so I'm curious to find out what I'm doing wrong here?

** Update **

The suggestion below i.e changing https:// to // worked on staging, but doesn't work when I put the site live! can anyone suggest anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Could this be because the browser does not show unsecure content when the page is loaded over https?

Try changing to a [protocol relative URL](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/), e.g. start the URL with '//' instead of 'https://'

Comment: Seems to have worked on our staging server, yet when posted to live this fails still.